# Themes are not picking from en-rGB

Tags: android, localization

In my application 2 locales are integrated en and en-rGB.

Strings are picking correctly from the values folder according to language 
But themes and styles are not picking from en-rGB.

Anyone please suggest me

Comment: I'm assuming you have made the proper folders: `drawable-en-*dpi`, `drawable-en-rGB-*dpi` (replace * with **l**, **m**, **h**, **xh**, **xxh**, **xxxh**) where to store your graphical resources.

Comment: I have tried with drawable-en-rGB-xxhdpi also but , Those drawbles not showing instead of them default drawbles are showing . same for themes(styles) also.Working fine for strings ,

Comment: You could alternatively try the new `-b+en+GB` variant.

Comment: "-b+en+GB " please explain briefly

Comment: `-b`: constant `+en`: language (replaces `-en`) `+GB`: region (replaces `-rGB`)

Comment: explain  me the how the drawable folder name "drawable-b+en+rGB" is it?

Comment: Exactly. Plus the eventual `-*dpi` slots.

Comment: I have created drawable-en-rGB-xxhdpi, but no luck

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, unfortunately.

Comment: i have resolved this issue . by resetting the locale from Android N onwards